# patsy formula - adding powers of a factor

Tags: python, patsy

I use patsy to build design matrix. I need to include powers of the original factors. For example, with the regression [image: y~x1+x1^2+x2+x2^2+x2^3], I want to be able to write

```
patsy.dmatrix('y~x1 + x1**2 + x2 + x2**2 + x2**3', data)
```

where data is a dataframe that contains column y, x1, x2. But it does not seem to work at all. Any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Patsy has a special interpretation of `**` that it inherited from R. I've considered making it automatically do the right thing when applied to numeric factors, but haven't actually implemented it... in the mean time, there's a general method for telling patsy to switch to using the Python interpretation of operators, instead of the Patsy interpretation: you wrap your expression in `I(...)`. So:

```
patsy.dmatrix('y~x1 + I(x1**2) + x2 + I(x2**2) + I(x2**3)', data)
```

([More detailed explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36539093/1925449))

Answer (score 0):

Patsy does not seem to manage power representation (yet?). A way to get around can be found here: [python stats models - quadratic term in regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978948/python-stats-models-quadratic-term-in-regression)