# Python equivalent for poly(x, 2) adds an orthogonal polynomial of degree 2

Tags: python, r, statsmodels, glm

Here is the R code

```
model1 <- glm(wt82_71 ~ qsmk + sex + race + poly(age, 2, raw = TRUE)   + education + poly(smokeintensity, 2, raw = TRUE) + poly(smokeyrs, 2, raw = TRUE) + exercise + active + poly(wt71, 2, raw = TRUE) + qsmk:smokeintensity,data = nhefs)
```

---

In Python I wrote:

```
mod3 = smf.glm(formula='qsmk ~ sex + race + education + exercise + active + poly(age,2) + poly(smokeintensity,2) + poly(smokeyrs,2) + poly(wt71,2)', family=sm.families.Binomial(), data=nhefs).fit()
mod3.summary()
```

What would `poly()` be in python?
Here is some comments 
model 1: regression on covariates, allowing for some effect modification
notes:

(1) poly(x, 2) adds an orthogonal polynomial of degree 2, add the argument raw = TRUE if you want it to produce the same coefficients as would x + x^2

(2) x1*x2 enters the main effects of x1 and x2 and their product term
x1:x2 enters just the product term (necessary here for smokeintensity because we want smokeintensity treated linearly in the interaction but quadratically in the main effect and thus a linear term for smokeintensity is not estimable)

(3) observations with missing values are automatically deleted

Comment: you should probably be explicit about what module `smf` refers to

Comment: its from the statmodels http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, `poly` for polynomial basis functions of continuous variables are not yet supported by patsy. The existing `poly` is for ordered categorical variables.

Numpy has `vander` functions for various polynomial bases that can be used directly in a formula.

Whether orthogonalizing on an existing dataset is useful or not is debatable. I prefer not to because then the basis functions do not change when the dataset changes.

https://github.com/pydata/patsy/issues/20
https://github.com/pydata/patsy/pull/92/files

As alternative, it is possible to directly specify power terms, see [python stats models - quadratic term in regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978948/python-stats-models-quadratic-term-in-regression) but that will not orthogonalize.