# Reciprocals in patsy

Tags: python, patsy

Patsy's power doesn't allow for negative integers, so, if we have some series data `X`,

```
patsy.dmatrices('X + X**(-1)', X)
```

returns an error.  How would I add the reciprocal of X to such a patsy formula?

Comment: Is `(1 / X)` also not allowed?

Comment: Nope, 1 is reserved for constants.

Comment: Also, the way `/` is defined in patsy, this would compute `1 + 1:X`.

Comment: Which is patsy for **I** + **I** * **X**, where **I** is a constant vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The special patsy meaning of operators gets switched off inside embedded function calls; so if you write `X + 1 / x` then patsy interprets that as the special patsy `+` and `/` operators, but if you write something like `X + sin(1 / X)`, then patsy continues to interpret the `+` as a special patsy operator, but the whole `sin(1 / X)` expression gets passed to Python to evaluate, and Python will evaluate the `/` as regular division.

So that's fine if we wanted to compute `sin(1 / X)`. But we don't (why would we?). We just want plain `1 / X`. So how can we do that?

Well, we can be tricky: we need a function call to trick patsy's parser into ignoring the `/` and giving it to Python -- but there's nothing that says that function has to *do* anything. We could just define an identify function:

```
def identity(value):
    return value
```

and then use that in a formula like `X + identity(1 / X)`.

And in fact, this trick is so handy that patsy has already predefined an function for you, and provides it as a [built-in](https://patsy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/builtins-reference.html) called `I(...)`. Generally, you can think of `I(...)` as a kind of quoting operator -- it's a way to say "hey patsy, please do not try to interpret anything in this region, just pass it through to Python kthx".

So to answer your original question: try writing `dmatrix("X + I(1 / X)", data)`

(Next question: why this weird hack with the function `I` and everything? The answer to that is that this is how R did it 30 years ago, and I couldn't think of anything sufficiently better to be worth breaking compatibility.)

Comment: I know I've asked an obscure question when I finally get an answer 6 months later from the guy who wrote the program that I'm asking about.

Comment: I’m wondering how patsy would handle things like $I(X%in%c(“A”, ”B”, ”D”))$ which is very straight forward in R

Comment: Thank you! As I love R and I have to use python, I'm so glad about this.. :) yet, this I() expression could be mentioned a bit more obvious somewhere in the documentation. Maybe or probably it is but it took me an hour until I found this post here.. however, thanks!